# How can I sort multiple lines of strings by numbers within the strings in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a txt file with multiple strings of:

```
John finished the game after 3 rounds in 45 seconds
James finished the game after 3 rounds in 65 seconds
Jane finished the game after 2 rounds in 15 seconds
```

How can I sort these results by comparing the number of rounds first and the time it took each player to finish the game to return a re-arranged list like:

```
Jane finished the game after 2 rounds in 15 seconds
John finished the game after 3 rounds in 45 seconds
James finished the game after 3 rounds in 65 seconds
```

I have tried using

```
lead_arr = [] 
File.open("game_results.txt", "r+") do | line | 
  line.each_line do |text| 
    lead_arr << text.split
  end
end
leader = lead_arr.sort_by(lead_arr[7].to_i)
```

Comment: What code do you have so far? What have you tried?

Comment: I have put that code into the question. I added some `end` statements which seemed to be missing in your comment. If it is wrong, or if you could please explain what happens, why it did not work, then please click the edit link (at bottom of the question) and change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer a more OO-ish approach. It's not as concise, but I think it is more intention revealing and easier to modify.

```
class Result
  def initialize(line)
    @line = line
  end

  def <=>(other)
    score <=> other.score
  end

  def score
    [rounds, seconds]
  end

  def rounds
    @line[/\d+ rounds/].to_i
  end

  def seconds
    @line[/\d+ seconds/].to_i
  end
end

File.open("game_results.txt")
 .each_line
 .sort_by { |line| Result.new(line) }
```

Comment: Nice one, Ben. I especially like the methods `rounds` and `seconds`.

Comment: Thanks @Ben. I used the regex on the rounds and seconds methods and they worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `sort_by` in combination with `scan` and `to_i`:

```
strings = [
  'John finished the game after 3 rounds in 45 seconds',
  'James finished the game after 3 rounds in 65 seconds',
  'Jane finished the game after 2 rounds in 15 seconds'
]

strings.sort_by { |string| string.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i) }
#=> ["Jane finished the game after 2 rounds in 15 seconds",
#    "John finished the game after 3 rounds in 45 seconds",
#    "James finished the game after 3 rounds in 65 seconds"]
```

Comment: OP implies that sort should be by number of rounds first, although no clear example of this in the sample data.

Comment: May be like `strings.sort_by {|s| s.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i) }`

Comment: You need to fix your answer or delete it.

Comment: Thanks @spickermann. I sorted my array with the regex in Ben's answer and is worked fine. Your answer was an eye opener too.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference here is the code I used.

```
lead_arr = []
  File.open("game_results.txt", "r") do | lines |
  lines.each_line do |text|
  lead_arr << text
  @leader = lead_arr.sort_by { |line| line[/\d+ rounds/].to_i &&  line[/\d+ seconds/].to_i}
```